# What is the basis upon which the concept that God and Allah are the same?

Tags: nature-of-god

On several occasions I have heard it said that both Islam and Christianity serve the same God. They have said that both serve the God of Abraham, however. In comparing the two, God's nature and Allah's nature seem to be totally different, and almost opposite.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an Islamic view, not a Christian one.

Comment: @stratton He's asking about a relationship between Christianity and Islam. If such a question is off limits on a Christianity site because it refers to Islam, presumably by the same reasoning it would be off limits on a Muslim site because it refers to Christianity. Unless someone creates a site just for asking questions about the relationships between different religions. And what's the point?

Comment: There's a comparative religious site. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58788/comparative-religion

Comment: As evidenced by how people tried to answer, this question would need much more work put into framing. As worded it primary comes down to "what is the basis for Islamic claim X" which is off topic for this site. If you want to ask something about Christianity you need to be much more specific.